# Python Cross Class function call with Kivy

Tags: python, function, class, kivy

I'd like to call the `reflist()` function from the `cpopup` class. I'm not really sure how to do that. After the `self.dismiss()` lines, I've tried a number of things.

`narr.reflist()` feels like it should work, but it doesn't. I think maybe because I need to refer to the instance of the class rather than the class itself, but I'm not quite sure what the instance name would be and how to reference it.

`narr().reflist()` is a bit more successful in that it does not through an error. But the result is unexpected (nothing happens). Perhaps it DOES work but I just dont understand variable scope in classes yet.

```
execfile("drawinglist.py")
    dlists = []
    dsource = []

    class cpopup(Popup):
        filechooser = ObjectProperty(None)
        def on_press_dismiss(self, *args):
            self.dismiss()
            #return False

        def load(self, path, filename):
            fdid = self.id
            bodycon = ObjectProperty(None)
            if fdid == "Narr":
                print parseNarrative(filename)
                dsource.append(filename)
                dlists.append(parseNarrative(filename))
                self.dismiss()
                narr.reflist()
            if fdid == "Dir":
                print parseFolder(filename, True)
                self.dismiss()
            if fdid == "Dl":
                print parseDrawinglist(filename)
                self.dismiss()

    class narr(BoxLayout):
        bodycon = ObjectProperty(None)
        dlists  = ObjectProperty(None)
        def loadNarr(self):
            pop = cpopup()
            pop.title="Select a file to generate Drawing List from"
            pop.id = "Narr"
            pop.filechooser.multiselect = True
            pop.open()

        def loadDir(self):
            pop = cpopup()
            pop.title="Select a Directory to load drawing list from."
            pop.id = "Dir"
            pop.filechooser.dirselect = True
            pop.open()

        def loadDl(self):
            pop = cpopup()
            pop.title="Select a drawing list (.pdfs) to generate list from"
            pop.id = "Dl"
            pop.filechooser.multiselect = True
            pop.open()

        def reflist(self):
            words = ""
            source = ""
            index = []

            for d in dlists:
                for a in d:
                    dwg = str(a)
                    if dwg not in index:
                        index.append(dwg)

            for l in dsource:
                fl = l[0]
                fl = fl.split("/")
                fl = fl[-1]
                source = source + fl +"\n"

            self.dlists.text = source
            self.bodycon.text = words

    class narrApp(App):
        def build(self):
            return narr()

    if __name__=="__main__":
        narrApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of ways, depends on the usage:

- If your classes are ***equal* to each other** call it in the instance of your second class through [`App.get_running_app()`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.get_running_app) like this (Kivy only):

  ```
  class MyWidget(Widget):
      def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
          self.app = App.get_running_app()
          self.app.my_widget = self

      def func(self, *args):
          pass

  class MyAnotherWidget(Widget):
      # you'll need this piece in the class you want to
      # access func() from and you'll need App instance
      # present too
      def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
          self.app = App.get_running_app()
          self.app.my_widget.func()
  ```
- master ↔ slave classes (one is always above):

  ```
  class Slave:
      def func(self, *args):
          pass

  class Master:
      # creating of the slave instance is required
      def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
          self.slave_class = Slave()
          self.slave_class.master_class = self
          self.slave_class.func()
  ```

  basically this is how `App` ↔ everything else relationship works. There's main master class and the only thing you do is putting additional references of your "slave" classes to the already created instance of "master" class.
- **staticmethod**s

  ```
  class Something:
      @staticmethod
      def static_func(*args):
          pass

  class SomethingElse:
      def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
          Something.static_func()
  ```

  the decorator allows you to use it like that, **but** you aren't able to access *anything* in the class the static method belongs to (no `self`, no class fun). You've surely already met them in some package in this shape: `Package.do_something(*args)`, well this could have been a static method.
- **classmethod**s

  ```
  class Something:
      def __init__(self, first=None, second=None, *args, **kwargs):
          print(first, second)

      @classmethod
      def class_func(cls, arg_list):
          special_Something = cls(arg_list[0], arg_list[1])
          return special_Something

  class SomethingElse:
      def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
          new_something = Something.class_func(['hi', 'there'])
  ```

  basically if you have for example a special format you want to pass to create a class, but the class has *different* input parameters, you do classmethod like that to make some sense of your input for the class you want to use it with.